# How to setup Performance Counters with NServiceBus in all the projects as per requirement

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I am trying to run the downloadable .Net(Version 4.6.1) projects provided by NServiceBus at the following link

```
https://docs.particular.net/samples/step-by-step/
```

When I try to run the application, I am getting the below error...

```
NServiceBus.PerformanceCounterHelper NServiceBus performance counter for '# of msgs pulled from the input queue /sec' is not set up correctly. To rectify this problem, consult the NServiceBus performance counters documentation.
```

How to run the code without getting `INFO` messages from each of the 4 projects in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue with Performance Counters, please have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/performance-counters?version=core_6#installing-counters) to learn how to install the counters and let me know if that resolved your issue.

To change the logging level, follow the instructions in [the documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/logging/#logging-levels-changing-the-logging-level-via-config-api). For NServiceBus version 6 you simply need to add the following code at the start of the main method in `Client`, `Server` and `Subscriber` projects:

```
var defaultFactory = LogManager.Use<DefaultFactory>();
defaultFactory.Level(LogLevel.Error);
```